# Retrieving values from more complex PHP function

Tags: php, laravel, function

If I have code like this

```
 $myFunction = new classFoo();                             //ie. class
 $myFunction-> new functionBar($value1,$value2,$value3);   //ie. function
```

I understand in a normal scenario, if I had this function...

```
function functionBar($value1,$value2,$value3){
    $answer=$value1+$value2+$value3
    return $answer
}
```

I could then plug into it like this

```
$answer=functionBar(1,2,3)
```

I could expect an echo of $answer to be 6, correct?

If I'm wrong there let me know, because my real issue is that the function is wrapped in a variable, which if I examine through console has what I need in it, but I can't get my head around how to access it with that extra layer involved.

Comment: `$answer` would be 6 :-)

Comment: LOL! ok my math is wrong, but is the concept right? I am going to edit but want to leave it up just for the irony

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking. You know the code in the first block won't parse, right? What do you mean by "the function is wrapped in a variable"?

Comment: `$myFunction-> new ` you cannot do that, it's a syntax error

Comment: Is `functionBar` defined inside of class `classFoo`?

Comment: Its inside of a laravel controller and it works but following those 2 lines of code at the top, variables inside the function are not definded outside of it

Comment: In general, variables inside functions are never defined outside of them.

Comment: Can you please re-write the question with a minimum, verifiable example, with psuedo-code that correctly shows the issue at hand?

Comment: OK thats my real issue.  If you understand the syntax I wrote is not the problem.  The $myFunction->new functionBar($value1,...) is working fine, but it returns a value.  Im trying to get at it but its buried in this laravel class controller format

Comment: So you're trying to get the result of a function within a controller, but you want that result in another piece of code elsewhere in the application. Is that the problem?

Comment: The top two lines work perfect with no issues to run the function which is written correctly.  If I was to write line 3 I would say $answer = (result from the function I just wrote above)

Comment: Sorry to go on about something that may be beside the point, but `$myFunction-> new functionBar($value1,$value2,$value3);` is a parse error in every version of PHP.

Comment: Don't panic, Its inside a laravel controller, not just straight PHP

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> because my real issue is that the function is wrapped in a variable
>   [snip] but I can't get my head around how to access it with that extra
>   layer involved.

Using your code and var names, and I've added the function which you do understand inside the class (is simply a function (aka "method") which essentially does the same thing - there are differences but not within the scope of your question).

It returns a value, which you can "wrap" (store) in a variable just the same as the function does without the class:

```
$myFunction = new foo();
$answer = $myFunction->functionBar(10, 20, 30);

class foo
{
    public function functionBar($value1, $value2, $value3)
    {
        return $value1 + $value2 + $value3;
    }
}
```

Your `$answer` var would contain "60". echoing it out would echo "60".

Comment: YES! that did it.  The key was just adding the $answer= before the $myFunction.  I was trying to get it after the fact.  Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem :) glad to help